# Azure Container: Docker Push Authentication Issue

Tags: powershell, docker, authentication

I have created a container registry in Azure and logged-in via Powershell. I then run a docker tag, which works, and subsequently, try docker push.

However, I receive an error "unauthorized" (see image); Admin user is enabled in access keys.

Any thoughts/work-arounds?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk5YE.jpg)

Comment: Please post error message by copy/pasting text...

Answer (score 0):

Docker tag doesn't require push permissions.  Make sure the user you're logging in with is a member of AcrPush, Contributor or Owner.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles